# What is the difference in method borrowing using call method and using "=" operator in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, methods, apply

Consider the following objects

```
var person1 = {
   name: 'Sam',
   age: 26,
   job: 'teacher',
   testMethod : function() {
     //do something
   }
};

var person2 = {
   name: 'John',
   age: 30,
   job: 'student'
};
```

I want to borrow testMethod from person1 to person2.

```
//Using = operator
person2.testMethod = person1.testMethod;
person2.testMethod();

//Using call method
person1.testMethod.call(person2)
```

What is the difference between these two ways of borrowing?

Comment: if your function doesn't uses any internal value of person1 then there's no problem, or if you have the same structure for both person1 and person2 then there's no problem.

Comment: @CodeManiac, in case of =, will a separate copy of method definition be created in memory?

Comment: No it won't it will create a reference only, which can be access `person2.testMethod` and in call method you do not create a reference on `person2`

Comment: The first version adds a new property to `person2`, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The `call` method will not add the `testMethod` to your second object `person2`, it will only change the binding of `this` inside `testMethod` body, so instead of `this` pointting to `person1` it will be pointting to `person2`.

*Example*:

```
var person1 = {
  firstName:"John",
  lastName: "Doe",
  fullName: function() {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
  }
}
var person2 = {
  firstName:"Mary",
  lastName: "Doe"
}

person1.fullName(); //this will yield John Doe
person1.fullName.call(person2); //this will yield Mary Doe

person2.fullName = person1.fullName;
person2.fullName(); //this will yield also Mary Doe
```

From MDN:

> The call() allows for a function/method belonging to one object to be
>   assigned and called for a different object.
>
> call() provides a new value of this to the function/method. With
>   call(), you can write a method once and then inherit it in another
>   object, without having to rewrite the method for the new object.